# Glossaries: Can I have counters on a per glossary basis?

Tags: glossaries, counters

I know how to change the counter used for referencing occurrences in the glossaries package options. For instance, I know how to use sections instead of pages.

Thing is, I have several glossaries in my document, and the most relevant counter for each of them is not the same (IMHO).

Is it possible to set a different counter for each glossary? For instance, can I use pages as a counter for a glossary, and sections for another?

If yes, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, looking at the documentation once more gave me the answer. I don't get how I missed this part as I have read it quite a number of times…

p. 174

```
\newglossary[〈log-ext〉]{〈name〉}{〈in-ext〉}{〈out-ext〉}{〈title〉}[〈counter〉]
```

So, it is easy to have counters on a per glossary basis, as you just may set the counter you want to use when creating a new glossary.

Answer (score -1):

You could perhaps use this snippet from my "personal documentation" :p

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\section{New Counter}

You could use \verb!\newcounter{}! to  create a new counting thing. For example if you wanted to create a thing called \textit{Crap} and count how many craps I have you can do: \\

\verb!\newcounter{Crap}! \newcounter{Crap} and then use \verb!\stepcounter{Crap}! to move these forward: \\

\noindent
\stepcounter{Crap}\arabic{Crap}{.} One crap \\
\stepcounter{Crap}\arabic{Crap}{.} Two crap \\
\stepcounter{Crap}\arabic{Crap}{.} Three crap \\

Then if you might want to step these up a notch (or down) you can use \verb!\addtocounter{Name}{number}! \addtocounter{Crap}{3} to  reset the count: \\

\noindent
\stepcounter{Crap}\arabic{Crap}{.} Some crap which has been jumped up by 3. \\

To print the numbers of these craps you use labeling definitions like \verb!\arabic{Crap}! or \verb!\alph{Crap}! where you want the numbering to appear: \\

\noindent
\stepcounter{Crap} More crap (\alph{Crap}). \\
\stepcounter{Crap} Even more crap (\alph{Crap}). \\

To get the section/chapter numbers with it simply add a counter definition for the desired document part and what you want to separate, like \verb!\arabic{section}.\alph{Crap}! \\

\noindent
\stepcounter{Crap} This is the last crap: \arabic{section}.\alph{Crap} \\

To get a dot or a semicolon or some such thing after a nude counter label just add the symbol in curly brackets after the numbering definition like \verb!\arabic{Crap}{.}!. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how your snippet is supposed to answer my question. You don't even load the glossaries package. I know how to create a custom counter and how to use it. I'll try to clarify my question with some example code as soon as possible.

Comment: @Melchisedech I apologise for being unhelpful. I suppose it was my mistake for assuming that my own try-anything-approach works for others.